# Is my understanding of strictness correct in this proof of a `foldl` rule?

Tags: induction, haskell

Exercise G in Chapter 6 of Richard Bird's *Thinking Functionally with Haskell* asks the reader to prove

```hs
foldl f e . concat  =  foldl (foldl f) e
```

given the rule

```hs
foldl f e (xs ++ ys)  =  foldl f (foldl f e xs) ys
```

There's no mention whether the given rule applies to infinite lists, nor does the answer in the book mention infinite lists. If my reasoning is correct, they are indeed both valid for infinite lists, provided `f` is strict.

The `undefined` case for the given rule requires this additional proof:

```hs
-- f is strict  ⟹  foldl f is strict  (i.e., foldl f undefined = undefined)

      foldl f undefined xs       =        undefined xs

-- case undefined
      foldl f undefined undefined         undefined undefined
--   =  {foldl.0}                        =  {?}
      undefined                           undefined

-- case []
      foldl f undefined []                undefined []
--   =  {foldl.1}                        =  {?}
      undefined                           undefined

-- case (x:xs)
      foldl f undefined (x:xs)            undefined (x:xs)
--   =  {foldl.2}                        =  {?}
      foldl f (f undefined x) xs          undefined
--   =  {f is strict}
      foldl f (undefined x) xs
--   =  {?}
      foldl f undefined xs
--   =  {induction}
      undefined xs
--   =  {?}
      undefined
```

As an aside, my proof for the dual of the above rule for `foldr`:

```hs
-- f x is strict  ⟹  foldr f is strict  (i.e., foldr f undefined = undefined)

      foldr f undefined xs       =        undefined xs

-- case undefined
      foldr f undefined undefined         undefined undefined
--   =  {foldr.0}                        =  {?}
      undefined                           undefined

-- case []
      foldr f undefined []                undefined []
--   =  {foldr.1}                        =  {?}
      undefined                           undefined

-- case (x:xs)
     foldr f undefined (x:xs)             undefined (x:xs)
--  =  {foldr.2}                         =  {?}
     f x (foldr f undefined xs)           undefined
--  =  {induction}
     f x (undefined xs)
--  =  {?}
     f x undefined                     
--  =  {f x is strict}
     undefined
```

The given rule:

```hs
-- f is strict  ⟹  foldl f e (xs ++ ys)  =  foldl f (foldl f e xs) ys

      foldl f e (xs ++ ys)       =        foldl f (foldl f e xs) ys

-- case undefined
      foldl f e (undefined ++ ys)         foldl f (foldl f e undefined) ys
--   =  {++.0}                           =  {foldl.0}
      foldl f e undefined                 foldl f undefined ys
--   =  {foldl.0}                        =  {f is strict  ⟹  foldl f is strict}
      undefined                           undefined ys
--                                       =  {?}
                                          undefined

-- case []
     foldl f e ([] ++ ys)                 foldl f (foldl f e []) ys
--  =  {++.1}                            =  {foldl.1}
     foldl f e ys                         foldl f e ys

-- case (x:xs)
     foldl f e ((x:xs) ++ ys)             foldl f (foldl f e (x:xs)) ys
--  =  {++.2}                            =  {foldl.2}
     foldl f e (x : (xs ++ ys))           foldl f (foldl f (f e x) xs) ys
--  =  {foldl.2}                         =  {induction}
     foldl f (f e x) (xs ++ ys)           foldl f (f e x) (xs ++ ys)
```

My solution to the exercise:

```hs
-- f is strict  ⟹  foldl f e . concat  =  foldl (foldl f) e

      foldl f e (concat xs)       =       foldl (foldl f) e xs

-- case undefined
      foldl f e (concat undefined)        foldl (foldl f) e undefined
--   =  {concat.0}                       =  {foldl.0}
      foldl f e undefined                 undefined
--   =  {foldl.0}
      undefined

-- case []
      foldl f e (concat [])               foldl (foldl f) e []
--   =  {concat.1}                       =  {foldl.1}
      foldl f e []                        e
--   =  {foldl.1}
      e

-- case (x:xs)
      foldl f e (concat (x:xs))           foldl (foldl f) e (x:xs)
--   =  {concat.2}                       =  {foldl.2}
      foldl f e (x ++ concat xs)          foldl (foldl f) (foldl f e x) xs
--   =  {f is strict  ⟹  foldl f e (xs ++ ys)  =  foldl f (foldl f e xs) ys}
      foldl f (foldl f e x) (concat xs)
--   =  {induction}
      foldl (foldl f) (foldl f e x) xs
```

Does this work? If so, is it often the case that rules restricted to finite lists can be made to work for all lists given additional strictness requirements like this?

There are several lines above with `{?}` given as my reasoning. They could be replaced by `{undefined x = undefined}`, but I am just guessing there. If that is true, how could it be justified?

Comment: (There have been discussions [What to do when the answer is already part of the question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question).)

Comment: @greybeard Is there a better place to ask this kind of question? I am studying on my own and don't know how else to check my understanding. I'd still like to know about `undefined x = undefined`; would it be appropriate to edit this question down to ask about that specifically?